# Vis Timeline Nested Group background entire row

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-timeline

So I have a pretty interesting timeline that I build with Vis-timeline (visjs).

I want to know if there is a way to get the entire vis-group to extend the entire timeline row.

So the nested headers have different colors, would be cool to make the entire row the same color.

[image]

So I managed to do this for the first group by just targeting 
.vis-foreground .vis-group:first-child

But that is only useful for the first Nested group.

Anybody that might have any ideas on how to achieve this, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create a type "background" item?

item types: String  no  The type of the item. Can be 'box' (default), 'point', 'range', or 'background'. Types 'box' and 'point' need a start date, the types 'range' and 'background' needs both a start and end date.